# Can't get grub2 to install and be able to dual boot windows and ubuntu from same SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had Elementary OS running for awhile alongside my W10, but I wanted to switch to Kubuntu while keeping my W10. Something went wrong in installation, so I went ahead and installed ubuntu 20.04 instead. Now, I only have legacy boot options and cannot use grub2 as UEFI to be able to boot into either Ubuntu 20.04 or W10.

How can I get around this issue? I have four partitions, one of which is windows. I have heard it's a bad idea to install grub into a partition. I think a similar question has been asked before, but apologies since I am rather new to linux. Thank you.

Best,
George

Comment: You can only boot both Windows and Ubuntu from the same disk if they are installed in the same BIOS/UEFI mode. It sounds like your Windows is installed in UEFI mode, so you must install Ubuntu in UEFI mode also. Rufus has a UEFI "Partition scheme". If you use that when making the boot disk it will only boot in UEFI mode which will ensure that Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode and will be compatible with your Windows. After install run`sudo update-grub` to put Windows on the Ubuntu grub menu.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode as C.S.Cameron suggests.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode to be Compatible with Windows

You can only boot both Windows and Ubuntu from the same disk if they are installed in the same BIOS/UEFI mode.

It sounds like your Windows is installed in UEFI mode, so you must install Ubuntu in UEFI mode also.

Rufus has a GPT "Partition scheme". If you use that when making the boot disk Ubuntu Live will only boot in UEFI mode, which will ensure that Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode and will be compatible with your Windows.

[image]

After install run `sudo update-grub` to put Windows on the Ubuntu grub menu.